# I have trouble finding my substring in a larger string

Tags: python

I have a dictionary

```
dic_enz = {EcoRI:G^AATTC}
```

and I want to find the number of times the value `G^AATTC` occurs in a larger string `my_seq` and I know there will be `3` but it returns me `0`.

This is my code

```
first_enz = dic_enz.get('EcoRI')
first_seq = first_enz.replace('^', '')
print(my_seq.count(first_seq))
```

The thing is that when I replace `first_seq` with `GAATTC` it works.

Comment: What is in `my_seq`?

Comment: Why do you think the answer is three?  Based on the question as it exists now, I don't see three.  Are you missing some input?

Comment: You need quotes around the key and value in the dictionary. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried `count` ...?

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar said in the comments (I was typing the answer when he/she commented), you should surround the keys and values of a dictionary if they are not variables or numbers:

```py
dic_enz = {"EcoRI": "G^AATTC"}

my_seq = "foo1GAATTCfoo2GAATTCfoo3GAATTCfoo4"

first_enz = dic_enz.get('EcoRI')
first_seq = first_enz.replace('^', '')
print(my_seq.count(first_seq))
```

This outputs `3`.

Answer (score 0):

As @BlueSheepToken said, it is just a matter of using [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) and the right pattern. Look:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 12 2019, 14:45:07) 
[GCC 9.1.1 20190605 (Red Hat 9.1.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s='G^AATTCaaaaG^AATTCbbbG^AATTCccccddefffG^AATTCa'
>>> pattern='G^AATTC'
>>> s.count(pattern)
4
>>>
```

If the pattern you want to count is `G^AATTC` why are you looking for `GAATTC`?

Comment: look closely in the question. OP actually DOES use `count`

Comment: Yeah. But with the wrong ```pattern```. If the string contains ```G^AATTC```, why is he looking for ```GAATTC``` (```first_enz.replace('^', '')```)?

Comment: So basically your answer is "don't remove the `^` characters from the pattern"

Comment: No. It is use the right pattern.

Comment: Because my string dose not contain '^' so I have to remove '^' and look for GAATTA